# Stop UTC formatting while importing data to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date, timezone, utc, database

I have db dump

```
{ "date": {"$date": 1441927937814}}
```

And when I do import to mongo database using

```
mongoimport
```

I get this time but UTC formatted, I mean, as I think, my local timezone is MSK so it subtracts 3 hours. What I need is:

```
2015-09-11T02:32:17.814000
```

but what I get is:

```
2015-09-10T23:32:17.814000
```

How can I stop time formatting to UTC?

Comment: Well, unix timestamps ( which is what the data you are importing it ) are presented in UTC. Also MongoDB BSON `Date` objects are also **always** in UTC. This is a **good** thing. If you think your dates should be in your "locale" format, then you are wrong. What if someone from a different locale wants to view the data? How should that date be presented to them? Certainly not at the time within your locale, it needs to be presented as relative to "them". That is why you **always** store dates as UTC. So there is a point of reference to convert from.

Comment: If however you "exported" timestamp values that actually represent your "locale" time in error ( and you had to do some work to make that happen ) then it would be best to correct that export error, or otherwise adjust all times by the difference from UTC. That last is basic date math.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, thank you for answering. But still i miss something. For example i have timestamp 1441927937814 and it's since Unix epoch, and there is no info about timezone, am I right? And when i do mongoimport for any timestamp it always will be converted to UTC format? I mean it will be converted to UTC depending on my local time zone?

Comment: What you are ""missing" is the reason there is no timezone information is because those "milliseconds from epoch" **is** meaning from the UTC time. Therefore it is a UTC time to begin with and there is no local timezone in there. What I have already said explains that in full.

Comment: Ok, I think i understood. Thank you.